# how to use overloading >> << to array of pointers which consitst ojbect Departments (Departments**)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Department class
   `#include 
    #include 
    #pragma once

```
using namespace std;
class Department
{
// overload input output streams
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const Department &);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &, Department &);

private:
    string name;
    long id;

public:

    static int departmentsCounter; // count num of elements
    Department();
    // set get block
    void setId(long);
    void setName(string);
    string getName() { return name; }
    long getId() { return id; }

    // overload block 
    Department &operator=(const Department &); // instead copy constructor
    bool operator>(const Department &) const; // check if count of students greater than count of students in another department
    void operator+=(Department &); // add new course to course list of the student
    void operator=(Department &); // remove course from course list of the student

    ~Department();
};`
```

Department cpp

```
#include "Department.h"

int Department::departmentsCounter = 0;

Department::Department()
{
    name;
    id = 0;
}

void Department::setId(long _id)
{
    id = _id;
}

void Department::setName(string _name)
{
    name = _name;
}

// overload out put (without cource list)
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Department &s)
{
    output << "Department: \nName " << s.name << "\nid " << s.id << "\n-------------------------------------------------\n";
    return output;
}
// overload input without check of right input data
istream &operator>>(istream &input, Department &s) {
    cout << "\nEnter name: ";
    input >> s.name;
    cout << "\nEnter id: ";
    input >> s.id;
    return input;
}

Department &Department::operator=(const Department &s) {
    Department temp;
    name = s.name; 
    id = s.id;

    return temp;
}


Department::~Department()
{}
```

in main function use this
 `cout << *(departments_list)[size];`
but it does not work memory error sow i dint understand how to fix it. Maybe i should allocate memory in constructor,  but i din't know the length of string that i use like a name. Actualy my question is how to use operators overload to **Departments because i don't understand how it work by this side

Comment: **Department departments_list = 0;

Comment: Your error lies somewhere in the code you didn't post. The most likely culprit is that you're using an invalid pointer. (There are a few other issues, for instance that your extraction operator is interactive, and that the assignment doesn't return `*this`, but nothing that should cause any runtime errors.)

Comment: "but it does not work memory error sow i dint understand how to fix it"????? Wow, kudos for the effort made in asking this question. I'm sure that there will be plenty of users who will be happy to spend the same amount of effort in answering it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array or vectors of pointers, the proper syntax is:

```
cout << *(departments_list[size]);
```

*Note the change in position of `(` and `)`.

**Note:  the above assumes that `size` is an index variable within the limits of the array or vector.**

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click on the check mark.